# Reset CSS on rotation

Tags: javascript, css

I'm using some CSS to set the size of an image element on my page. The problem is, if a user rotates their mobile it stays fixed to the original dimensions. Is there a way to detect the rotation, and recalculate the sizes elements should be on the page?

Here's what I've found so far...

```
window.addEventListener("orientationchange", function() {}, false);
```

Comment: Media queries and the `orientationchange` event will cover some bases, but for a truly cross-browser and cross-device solution the safest way to do this is a manual check for orientation that calculates it based on viewport width and height on resize event.

Comment: @Ennui it's not so much about having a different set of css for portrait and landscape, it's just recalculating what 100% width looks like when the user rotates their device. Currently it just sticks at whatever the width was previously.

Answer (score 2):

Sure, you can use CSS [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries) for this type of thing:

```
/* Portrait */
@media screen and (orientation:portrait) {
    /* Portrait styles */
}
/* Landscape */
@media screen and (orientation:landscape) {
    /* Landscape styles */
}
```

> A media query consists of a media type and at least one expression
>   that limits the style sheets' scope by using media features, such as
>   width, height, and color. Media queries, added in CSS3, let the
>   presentation of content be tailored to a specific range of output
>   devices without having to change the content itself.

You can extend media queries to be fairly specific if you want to extend and target desktop vs mobile devices etc..

Alternatively- using JS you could simply do:

```
var orientation = null;
window.onresize = function (event) {
    orientation = parseInt(window.innerHeight / window.innerWidth) !== 0 ? 'portrait' : 'landscape';
    /* logic for if orientation == portrait etc goes here */
};
```